# New applications with middle click of mouse in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I've always used the middle button of my mouse to open a new instance of a program or Windows from the taskbar in Windows 7.  Until recently, that used to make the new Windows appear on top of other open Windows.

Now though, be it a Word Doc, Windows Explorer or anything else, it opens a new instance of the program  But it flashes orange and the Windows is behind everything else, meaning a few more clicks to get where I want.

I don't recall changing any settings to make this behavior different.

Can anyone tell me how to get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's annoying. Try this registry fix:

1. Open Start > Run and type “regedit” (without quotes)
2. Navigate to the following path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop
3. Set "ForegroundLockTimeout" value = 0. (If that doesn't exist, then create a new DWORD value with that name).
4. Exit registry and restart windows.